# Getting lambda undefined error in linearRegCostFunction.m when including lambda in learningcurve.m

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am getting lambda undefined erorr,even when I have already defined lambda=0 twice. This error occurs only when I include lambda variable in the learningcurve.m function. If I comment out the for loop it works well however I do get some warnings. This is from andrew ng machine learning course week 6. I encourage you to check ex5.m I have included the link for this main file

https://github.com/AladdinPerzon/Courses/blob/master/MOOCS/Coursera-Machine-Learning/Programming%20Assignment%205/ex5/ex5.m

```
function [error_train, error_val] =learningCurve(X, y, Xval, yval, lambda)

% Number of training examples
m = size(X, 1);

% You need to return these values correctly
error_train = zeros(m, 1);
error_val   = zeros(m, 1);

for i=1:m   
  [theta]=trainLinearReg([ones(i, 1), X(1:i, :)], y(1:i,:),lambda);
  [error_train(i), ~]=linearRegCostFunction(X(1:i,:),y(1:i),0);
  [error_val(i), ~]=linearRegCostFunction(Xval,yval,theta,0);
  
endfor
end
```

```
m = length(y); % number of training examples

% You need to return the following variables correctly 
J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
% Instructions: Compute the cost and gradient of regularized linear 
%               regression for a particular choice of theta.
%
%               You should set J to the cost and grad to the gradient.
%

h = X * theta;

theta = [0 ; theta(2:end , :)];
pen_reg = lambda*(dot(theta,theta))/(2*m);
J = 1/(2 * m) * sum((h - y).^2) + pen_reg;

pen_grad = (lambda/m).*theta;
grad = 1/m .* ((h-y)' * X)' + pen_grad;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This has nothing to do with Python, and MATLAB is not Octave. Please don't tag spam. Please read [mcve] and then provide us with an example that we can run, i.e. include sample input in the question itself, not behind some off-site link.

Comment: well, if you're defining lambda=0 somewhere, it sure isn't shown here. you're probably failing to define lambda at some point. run your scripts through a debugger with appropriate breakpoints and check.